# How to uninstall a manually installed Node.js and Yarn on Linux?

Tags: node.js

I am on Linux.

- I downloaded the "latest features" Node.js binaries from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download).
- I unpacked them to a folder and added the contained `bin` directory to my `.bashrc`. (`export PATH="$HOME/Node.js/v20.2.0/bin:$PATH"`)
- Then, [as recommended here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install), I ran `corepack enable` to get Yarn support.
- Also as recommended there, I ran `corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate`  to upgrade Yarn.
- I ran a `yarn install` command in a folder.

Now **I want to completely uninstall Node.js and Yarn**. How would I do that? Which `cache`/`config`/`etc` folders have above commands created?

Would I be correct that these are

```
~/.cache/node
~/.npm
~/.yarn
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The manual removal of these folders (if they exist) ...

```
~/.cache/node
~/.cache/yarn
~/.npm
~/.yarn
```

... and these files (if they exist) ...

```
~/.yarnrc
~/.node_repl_history
```

... plus the installation folder (here `~/Node.js/v20.2.0`) removes all traces of Node.js and Yarn.